# Representing Text for Section Labeling While Avoiding Bias

Tags: machine-learning, references, text-mining, information-retrieval

**Problem Background:** I have free form text data with more or less arbitrary formatting/structure, but semantically it can be broken down like this:

```
{header}
{title}
{subtitle}
{article}
{boilerplate}
```

However, not all sections need necessarily have Length > 0, except `{article}` and `{title}`. Another thing to consider is that by far the longest section is `{article}`, often $\gtrapprox 90\%$ of the whole text. In the end I want to find those sections within a given text.

The `{header}` is not just a line or two, it often is several lines of text unrelated to the other sections, and is usually a couple of sentences addressing the following `{article}` and what should be done with it. In other words the `{header}` is often a full email, which precedes the `{article}`. All remaining sections are related to the `{article}` section.

**Example Data:** An example might look like this:

> *Hello Mr. X,*
>
> *I've attached a new press release regarding Y and would like for you to do
>   Z with it.*
>
> *If you have any questions I would be glad to answer them.*
>   *Best Regards,*
>   Mr. X
>
> **Awesome News**
>   *Really awesome news about some stuff.*
>
> A long and nicely formatted couple of paragraphs with pictures tables and
>   whatnot follows...
>
> To learn more visit some website
>   Or contact Mr. X

**Attempt:** I think trying to label individual words according to the section they are in won't do me much good, not without training some deep network with millions of samples, which I don't have.

I've thought about other approaches. Such as focusing purely on the structure, e.g.:

- Line Length
- #words in line
- Capitalization
- Relative Position of Line in Text
- Number of paragraphs
- ...

i.e. all kinds of structure I can find in the text. This approach while, presumably, not as much as a purely word based approach would still result in a lot of bias towards the `{article}` section.

Another thought I had was to transform the text labeling into an image segmentation problem. Since, most of the time, the sections could be easily divided with four horizontal lines if converted into a picture, and the font type/size plus other formatting and position indicators would also help.

**Question:** Could you maybe point me in a possible direction I could take to tackle the problem ?

What would be a good model ?

Is there maybe some paper which discusses text part segmentation as I want to do it and how to avoid bias ?

Is the problem maybe not a good fit to be solved through a ML approach ?